# Can't open localhost in the browser on port given in docker-compose

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, containers

I am trying to build and run django application with docker and docker-compose.
`docker-compose build example_app` and `docker-compose run example_app` run without errors, but when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` page doesn't open, I'm just getting "page is unavailable" error in the browser.
Here is my Dockeffile, docker-compose.yml and project structure

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9-buster

RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements_dev.txt /app/requirements_dev.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  example_app:
    image: example_app
    build:
      context: ../
      dockerfile: ./docker/Dockerfile
    command: bash -c "cd app_examples/drf_example && python manage.py runserver"
    volumes:
      - ..:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

project structure:

```
──app
──app_examples/drf_example/
  ────manage.py
  ────api
  ────drf_example
──requirements.txt
──requirements_dev.txt
──docker/
  ────docker-compose.yml
  ────Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Django apps *bind* to 127.0.0.1 meaning that they'll only accept connections from the local machine. In a container context, the local machine is the container, so your app won't accept connections from outside the container.

To get it to accept connections from anywhere, you add the bind address to the `runserver` command. In your case, you'd change the command in your docker-compose.yml file to

```
command: bash -c "cd app_examples/drf_example && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to use the flag `--service-ports` when using docker compose `run` app instead of docker compose `up`, like this:

```
docker compose run --service-ports app
```

My docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "${DJANGO_BIND_PORT}:${DJANGO_BIND_PORT}"
    command: [
      "./scripts/start-development.sh"]
```

My ./scripts/.env:

```
DJANGO_BIND_PORT=8000
```

My ./scripts/start-development.sh:

```
set -e

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py seed_db --create-super-user

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:${DJANGO_BIND_PORT:-8000}
```

---

Related [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_run/#description)

Related [Docker compose git thread](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4799) with more info

Answer (score -2):

you need to expose port 8000 in your Docker file

```
FROM python:3.9-buster

EXPOSE 8000

RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
COPY ./requirements_dev.txt /app/requirements_dev.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
```

Comment: The EXPOSE command mainly documents what ports the container uses, but it doesn't do anything beyond that. So while it's nice to document that it listens on port 8000, that's not what's causing the issue.

Comment: I see that you're correct. I swear I recalled running into that before and the EXPOSE fixing it. Obviously, I was wrong.